# Why do "int" and "sbyte" GetHashCode functions generate different values?

Tags: c#, hash

We have the following code:

```
int i = 1;
Console.WriteLine(i.GetHashCode());  // outputs => 1
```

This make sense and the same happen whit all integral types in C# except sbyte and short.
That is:

```
sbyte i = 1;
Console.WriteLine(i.GetHashCode());   //  outputs => 257
```

Why is  this?

Comment: Why not? what's wrong with 257?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic "Why is it not 1, as with int.GetHashCode?" :)

Comment: Because it is different type. Is there any reason why it should be 1?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic "But it is also an integer type. So why is the GetHashCode implementation not uniform?" (Looking at it another way, why is `int.GetHashCode` so boring?)

Comment: I believe that you are confused about purpose of `GetHashCode`. You should treat the int implementation where 1 => 1 as coincidence. By following same logic, you could say that anything in .NET is an object so e.g. int and string should have uniform implementation. Hash functions should provide good distribution across integer range. If it would return the same value, all hash values would be located in lower 16 bits.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic yes we know that the result of `GetHashCode` is unspecified. But I don't see why `(int)this ^ ((int)this << 8)` is better than `(int)this`. So why do the extra work? (I know it's negligible compared to the cost of the remainder operator)

Comment: It is better, as I said, because you want better distribution across integer range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the source of that method (`SByte.GetHashCode`) is

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return (int)this ^ ((int)this << 8);
}
```

As for why, well someone at Microsoft knows that..

Comment: It would distribute the values in the sbyte domain more throughout the integer range (actually, only to ~32k) .. not sure about C#, but Java HashMap (etc), already use a re-distribution function ..

Comment: I think the .net hashtables simply mask away the sign, and then calculate the remainder. So I don't really see what this implementation gains.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Well, if pst is correct it would result in the items in the hash table being more evenly distributed (if there is a small range of numbers and a large hash table size) which means less collisions which means better efficiency.

Comment: @Servy At least for positive numbers, multiplying with 257 has no effect on the bin distribution at all. 257 is prime, and thus co-prime to any table size except 257. The only interesting effect this has is how it maps negative numbers to positive numbers. But I don't know if that's an advantage over masking away the sign.

Comment: @CodesInChaos What's your basis for assuming that the number is multiplied by 257?  Did you not look at harold's code to see how 257 is generated?

Comment: @Servy yea that's pretty much multiplying by 257, except for negative numbers, it gets more funny there.

Comment: @harold It's equivalent to (256*x)+x

Comment: For positive numbers this is equivalent to `257*x`, for negative numbers to `-255*x`. Unclear to me why `(x>=0 ? 257*x : -255*x)%n` is supposed to be better than `(0x7FFFFF&x)%n`.

Comment: @Servy It's only equivalent to ` (256*x)+x` if x is positive. And `(256*x)+x` is `257*x`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Actually I forgot an abs, so it is different; the general case is  `abs(256*x)+x`.  That applies to both positive/negative values

Comment: What I also find curious is that, suppose this helps, why isn't it done for the unsigned byte as well?

Comment: @harold, if the source of int.gethashcode() is truly "(int)this ^ ((int)this << 8)", then why does the value for test = 31695424 after running int test = (int)123456 ^ ((int)123456 << 8); ?  I would expect it to equal 123456. If you run test = 123456; test = test.GetHashCode();  test still equals 123456.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's all about values distribution. As the GetHashCode method return type is int for the type sbyte the values are going to be distributed in intervals of 257. For this same reason for the long type will be colisions.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that it is probably done to avoid clustering of hash values.

As `GetHashCode` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) says:

> For the best performance, a hash function must generate a random 
>   distribution for all input.
>   Providing a good hash function on a class can significantly affect the 
>   performance of adding those objects to a hash table. In a hash table with
>   a good implementation of a hash function, searching for an element takes 
>   constant time (for example, an O(1) operation).

Also, as [this excellent article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) explains:

> Guideline: the distribution of hash codes must be "random"
>   By a "random distribution" I mean that if there are commonalities in the objects being hashed, there should not be similar commonalities in the hash codes produced. Suppose for example you are hashing an object that represents the latitude and longitude of a point. A set of such locations is highly likely to be "clustered"; odds are good that your set of locations is, say, mostly houses in the same city, or mostly valves in the same oil field, or whatever. If clustered data produces clustered hash values then that might decrease the number of buckets used and cause a performance problem when the bucket gets really big.

Comment: But can you explain why it improves the distribution?

Comment: I am not a mathematician, so I wouldn't be that courageous :). However, I suspect that it is related to the implementation of HashTable and Dictionary classes, default bucket settings, etc.

Comment: I would also expect it to behave better if you have an `sbyte` field in your class and use its hash as a part of your class hash function (the often use `h = h * 23 + field.GetHashCode()` idiom).