# Inconsistency in Equals and GetHashCode methods

Tags: c#, .net, equals, hashcode

After reading this question [Why do "int" and "sbyte" GetHashCode functions generate different values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501979/why-do-int-and-sbyte-gethashcode-functions-generate-different-values) I wanted to dig further and found following behavior:

```
sbyte i = 1;            
int j = 1;
object.Equals(i, j) //false (1)
object.Equals(j, i) //false (2) 
i.Equals(j) //false (3)
j.Equals(i) //true (4)
i == j //true (5)
j == i //true (6)
i.GetHashCode() == j.GetHashCode() //false (7)
```

1. Difference between (3) and (4) breaks the requirement that Equals should be symmetric.
2. Difference between (2) and (4) is not coherent with [MSDN specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx) that says:

   > If the two objects do not represent the same object reference and
   >   neither is null, it calls objA.Equals(objB) and returns the result.
   >   This means that if objA overrides the Object.Equals(Object) method,
   >   this override is called.
3. Difference between (3) and (5) means that operator == returns true, however objects are not equal in terms of Equals.
4. Difference between (4), (5), (6) and (7) means that two objects are equal in terms of operator == and Equals, however they have different hash codes.

I'm very interested if anyone can explain why such in my opinion inconsistent behaviour is observed in rather fundamental .NET types.

Comment: That's was what I think when see that. Very thanks for see the core of the problem empi

Comment: All those 'inconsistencies' follow from the implicit conversion from sbyte to int.

Comment: @pst `a.Equals((object)b)` certainly implies `a.GetHashCode()==b.GetHashCode()`. And I'd call any type for which `==` behaves differently from `Equals` broken, even if .net doesn't strictly require this. (disregarding implicit conversions, and assuming runtime type and static type are identical)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your problem is that you missed the implicit conversion in `i.Equals(j)`. It goes to the overload `int.Equals(int)`. Here you're comparing `i` and `(int)j`, which are the same thing. The same implicit conversion happens for `==`.

The other comparisons work on an `int` and a `sbyte`, which by definition are different. `j.Equals(i)` goes to the overload `int.Equals(object)`, because the argument isn't implicitly convertible to `sbyte`.

`Equals` is symmetric for them, but your calling code isn't. If you suppress the implicit conversion with `i.Equals((object)j)`, it'll return `false`, showing that `Equals` is indeed symmetric.