# Why does comparing a *nullable* decimal with `0` differ from comparing a decimal with `0`?

Tags: c#, nullable, equality

Can someone explain why `result1` is `false` and `result2` is `true`? code is given below:

```
namespace TestCsharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Order objOrder = new Order(0.0M);

            bool result1 = objOrder.PriceNullable.Equals(0);//returns false
            bool result2 = objOrder.PriceNullable.Value.Equals(0);// returns true
        }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public decimal? PriceNullable { get; set; }
        public Order(decimal? priceNullable)
        {
            PriceNullable = priceNullable;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Related question: [Inconsistency in Equals and GetHashCode methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502613/inconsistency-in-equals-and-gethashcode-methods)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `System.Decimal` exposes an overload of [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a6s0tsh.aspx) that can accept a `Decimal` value, and your second case is invoking *that* method (having converted the `int` parameter to a `decimal` using an [implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131060.aspx)) and returning true.

Whereas in the first case, the [`Nullable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7b1e4z6.aspx) is trying its best, but can only invoke `Object.Equals` which will fail when comparing between an `int` and a `decimal`. If your first call was:

```
bool result1 = objOrder.PriceNullable.Equals(0M);
```

You'd be comparing two `decimal`s, and it will now return `true`.

---

The `Nullable` generic `Equals` method can invoke neither the implicit conversion from `int` to `decimal`, nor the overload of equals that accepts a `decimal` value.

Comment: I got it. When we assign value to "PriceNullable" it is converted to "decimal"(because "PriceNullable" is of type decimal), so we need to compare "PriceNullable" with decimal values.

Answer (score 2):

The first check is returning false because the value passed to it is not of type decimal. If you specify `M` with 0 you will get true.

```
bool result1 = objOrder.PriceNullable.Equals(0M);
```

Answer (score 1):

If we check the deffinition of `Nullable<T>.Equals`:

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Indicates whether the current <see cref="T:System.Nullable`1"/> object is equal 
 /// to a specified object.
 /// </summary>
 ///...
 // true if the <paramref name="other"/> parameter is equal to the current 
 // object; otherwise, false. 
        public override bool Equals(object other);
```

So you have  compared `Nullable<decimal>` and an `int`. They are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

[Nullable.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7b1e4z6.aspx)

In first case you compare int object to decimal object.
if you have

```
bool result1 = objOrder.PriceNullable.Equals(0.0M);
```

result1 will be *true*.

Answer (score -1):

When you use

`objOrder.PriceNullable.Equals(0)`
it compares the object `decimal?` with 0 a `decimal` digit which is `False`

But when you do

`objOrder.PriceNullable.Value.Equals(0)` it compares a decimal value which is 0 and returns `true`

Do this for more clarification

```
decimal? nullableZero = 0;
bool result3 = objOrder.PriceNullable.Equals(nullableZero);// returns true
```

Comment: -1 Doesn't explain the real issue, namely the implicit conversion from `int` to `decimal` in one case, which doesn't happen in the other.